# Excel Send As Attachment is sending cached version of file

Tags: email, caching, excel, email-attachments, vba

I have a macro-based file built in Excel 2010.  It contains sensitive data.  In order to prevent the sensitive data from being disseminated willy nilly, I've created a password to the file.  I've also created macros that prevent saving the file as anything other than a PDF.  So basically, I've done everything I can think of to prevent the file from being sent out in its excel format.

However, my clever (or not so clever) users have found an inadvertent workaround.  If they fill out the form and then just hit the Send as Attachment option in Excel, they can send out the file pre-filled with data and having all functionality intact.  This circumvents my security measures and also annoys me because I've told the users specifically NOT to send out this file.

In researching online, it seems there is no way to turn off the email as attachment function.  There also does not seem to be any way to detect an email event (something equivalent to the Before_Print event).  I was wondering if the StackOverflow community might have any suggestions on how to resolve this.

Comment: Remove the send as attachment entry in the menu and add it back before your workbook loses focus? For example: http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm

Comment: `I've also created macros that prevent saving.... out in its excel format.` This is not good enough :) If the users disable macros then they will be able to save the file in a format other than a PDF. Why not create a PDF form and then let the user's fill that and send that you?

Comment: that would mean that I would have to do the prep of these forms for the entire company, which is not in my job description!  :-)  Also, if they disable macros, they disable a large part of the functionality that makes the tool a risk (it contains pay info).

Comment: I saw the link on how to modify the UI to remove the mail as attachment function using XML.  My preference is to not do that, just because if anything should happen while the user is working with my file and I don't have a chance to reset the UI, it will cause a problem.

Comment: mucking around with the riboon is fun; I'm pretty sure that XML is specific to the xlsx file - so if something happens while a user is in the file xl _will_ reset when another file is activated

Comment: @Jay currently doing a tidy up of any questions/answers I have been involved in - did my contribution help answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

I use the Custom UI Editor and play around with the XML. I've got a standard template I use that limits peoples toolbar in xl.

I'm sure there are workarounds but it might help:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="true">
<qat>
 <documentControls>
<control 
   idMso="FileSaveAs"
   screentip="SAVE AS..."
   supertip="Click here to save this file to another location."/>
<control 
   idMso="WindowSwitchWindowsMenuExcel"
   screentip="SWITCH EXCEL FILE"
   supertip="Click here to switch from this workbook to another open excel file."/>
<control 
   idMso="FilePrint"
   screentip="PRINT FILE"
   supertip="Click here to enable the print menu."/>
 </documentControls>
 </qat>
 </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with XML coding, and I'd hate to implement something I don't fully understand.  I'm getting the sense that there really isn't any workaround to my problem.  Is XML manipulation even possible in Excel 2007?  I have some users who are still stuck on that version.

Comment: it's possible if the file is ".xlsx" or "xlsm". Go to [Ron's](http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm) site for explanation. You need to download a little tool which is a bit like notepad. It's located [here](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2006/05/26/customuieditor.aspx) in a zipped file. I think it's just a case of closing your excel file in Excel. Open the little tool and do Open file and open your target xlsx file in there and then do Insert and pop in the custom file you require and copy in the code I supplied above ....try it on an experimental xlsx file

Comment: ok - works ok; you'll notice that when you open the file the ribbon changes and then when you close the file it goes back to how it was because the manipulation is part of the actual file now. It's a lot more stable than the old method of manipulating toolbars - which was prone to leaving peoples setting all messed up.

Comment: whytheq - would this modification allow removal of options under the File | Save & Send menu?  Is that even part of the Ribbon?

Comment: try the above first and see if you can get it to work. The close the xlsx file and open it again in the Custom UI Editor - this time comment out the section of the above which adds back the FileSaveAs button and save the file.

Comment: whytheq - thank you for your help.  This approach worked, but it's not the way I ended up going because I just didn't trust that it wouldn't screw up my users' computers.

Comment: @user2296377 I've been using it for 2 years - the files get distributed throughout our company. All users in our company are using recent versions of Excel.